# How to get last item in ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to get the last added item in an ArrayList to compare it to the next item I'm about to add to it.  If they are equal, continue. Like:

```
if (stringArray.get(stringArray.IndexOfLastItemAdded()) == compareLastItemToThis) {
    continue;
}
else {
    stringArray.add(compareLastItemToThis);
}
```

I know `IndexOfLastItemAdded` doesn't exist, but is there something similar to it?

Comment: Also note that you can not compare strings using the `==` operator. Rather, use `equals( compareListItemToThis )`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
stringArray.get(stringArray.size() - 1) ;
```

shoudl give u the last item in stringArray list

Comment: I think you mean stringArray.get(stringArray.size() - 1)